# How to assign cell values based on options from another list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am sure there is a simple formula for this but I have not been able to find a solution anywhere.

I am trying to fill a cell based on a list in a different tab.
In my main sheet, each row has a country assigned (multiple from each country). I am trying to assign the next column a region, based on the corresponding country. (eg - Nigeria = Africa, Spain = Europe).

in Column F the country is included, Column G needs to show the corresponding region. The region is one of 5 possible options from Sheet B.

Appreciate any help here!

[image: Sheet A]

[image: Sheet B]

Answer (score 0):

I have a draggable formula that works, but it's certainly not the best:

```
=IF(
    AND(Result!A2<>"", COUNTIF(INDEX(Result!A2='Main Sheet'!$A$2:$E),true)),
    INDEX('Main Sheet'!$A$1:$E$1,
          MAX(INDEX((Result!A2='Main Sheet'!$A$2:$E)*(COLUMN('Main Sheet'!$A$2:$E))))
         ), 
)
```

[image]
the main sheet:
[image: main]